# For $w\in\Bbb{C}$ with $|w|<1$, describe the set defined by $|z-w|\leq|1-\bar{w}z|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers, plane-geometry

> Let $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$ where $|w|<1$ (modulus). What is the set of all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $|z-w|\leq|1-\bar{w}z|$?

I've tried a few things with no luck. I wrote $z,w$ are complex numbers and used the inequality, but I don't know how to find the set that satisfies the inequality. Any solutions or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is the same as $|z-w|^2\leq|1-\overline{w}z|^2$, where
\begin{eqnarray*}
|z-w|^2&=&(z-w)(\overline{z-w})=(z-w)(\overline{z}-\overline{w})=z\overline{z}-\overline{w}z-w\overline{z}+w\overline{w}\\
&=&|z|^2+|w|^2-\overline{w}z-w\overline{z},\\
\ \\
|1-\overline{w}z|^2&=&(1-\overline{w}z)(\overline{1-\overline{w}z})=(1-\overline{w}z)(1-w\overline{z})=1-w\overline{z}-\overline{w}z+w\overline{w}z\overline{z}\\&=&1-w\overline{z}-\overline{w}z+|w|^2|z|^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Plugging this into the original inequality yields
$$|z|^2+|w|^2-\overline{w}z-w\overline{z}\leq1-w\overline{z}-\overline{w}z+|w|^2|z|^2,$$
and rearranging the terms shows that $1-|z|^2-|w|^2+|w|^2|z|^2\geq0$, or equivalently
$$(1-|z|^2)(1-|w|^2)\geq0.$$
Given that $|w|<1$ we also $1-|w|^2>0$, so dividing through by $1-|w|^2$ yields the inequality
$$1-|z|^2\geq0\qquad\text{ or equivalently }\qquad |z|^2\leq0.$$
So the set you are looking for is the closed unit disk.